# How to exit function from catch block in PHP

Tags: php, function

I try to get value from an external API, in failure i catch an exception, but i want to go out of my main function, can i do that into catch ?

```
public function test() 
{
    ....
    $val = this->getVal($id)

    this->getx($val);
    this->gety($val);
}

private function getVal($id)
{
    try {
        //trying to get value from an other API
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        // here i want to go out from test function ..
    }

    return $value;
}
```

Comment: throw('Get me out of here!') will jump out. but that's not exactly nice.

Comment: you can put try and catch in test function and if any exception generated then you can just use return directly in test to go out from test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cleanest solution, in my opinion, is to throw a specific exception and catch that where your test function is called. This way execution is stopped and resumed in the catch block.

```
try {
    test();
} catch (MyCustomException $e) {
    // Test has been halted
}

public function test() 
{
    ....
    $val = this->getVal($id)

    this->getx($val);
    this->gety($val);
}

private function getVal($id)
{
    try {
        //trying to get value from an other API
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        throw new MyCustomException;
    }

    return $value;
}
```

Comment: But i'm calling this function from an listener !

Comment: Please add the code that calls this function to your original question. This way I may be able to give you a specific example.

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious I can think of is to return something that exits the rest of test().
Example:

```
public function test() 
{
    ....
    $val = this->getVal($id)
    if($val !== false){
        this->getx($val);
        this->gety($val);
    }
}

private function getVal($id)
{
    try {
        //trying to get value from an other API
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        // here i want to go out from test function ..
        $value = false; // or null, or what suits the rest of the code
    }

    return $value;
}
```